# How to replace a pattern in one file, with the contents of another file, using sed?

Tags: regex, unix, text, replace, sed

Lets say I have `fileA`, with the contents

```
Hello, this is some
random text REPLACEHERE and some more
random text
```

and `fileB` with the contents

```
stuff that goes into
fileA, at that specific place
```

How do I properly replace `REPLACEHERE` inside `fileA`, with the contents of `fileB` ? Exactly in that place, just as if I was doing a simple regex operation ?

The closest I've got was

```
sed -i '/REPLACEHERE/r fileB' fileA
```

which only ends up appending fileB in the line after `REPLACEHERE` was found, and that's no good. I need it to be replaced exactly in place (I thought that's what the `i` flag was for actually).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably won't be that easy with `sed` only, I'd use a shell variable/command expansion:

```
sed -i "s/REPLACEHERE/$(cat fileB)/g" fileA
```

`-i` means that the changes will be saved to `fileA`, rather than printed to `stdout`.

Mind the slashes in `fileB`, by the way. If there are any, they will have to be escaped.